# Windows batch script: move files that contain duplicate lines

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, duplicates

Thank you in advance for any help.

I am requesting a batch script that I can run in windows xp.
This script should search a folder containing multiple files and look in each file to see if there are any duplicate lines in that file.  And if there is, then that file would be moved into a new folder.

The script below I know works to move a string to a new folder:

FOR %%a in (C:\test*) do (findstr /C:"string" "%%a" >nul && move /Y "%%a" "C:\new folder")

This is about the extent of my knowledge when it comes to scripts.

Could I please have it built on to instead searching for a specific string, but to identify if there are duplicate lines?  So it goes without saying that each line should be unique, otherwise I need to move the file to a new folder.

Thanks again for your assistance

Comment: Your script doesn't move the file; it copies it.

Comment: Search the site for batch duplicate lines. I bet you will find your answer.

Comment: Assuming you only mean duplicate consecutive lines I suggest get http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/ which gives you "uniq" tool. This test example should get you going `( echo bb & echo aa & echo aa) | uniq -c -d > tmp.txt & findstr "^ " tmp.txt` when exit code is 0 move the file.